# Coil AsyncImage not resolving

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I have not been able to get Coil to resolve for me. I've added the implementation to my gradle

`implementation('io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.2')`

I've added

`import coil.*` and I've tried `import coil.compose.AsyncImage` and neither have proven to be successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the dependency:

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")
```

Then you can import:

```
import coil.compose.AsyncImage
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I said that I've done this and no luck. `compose` is not found

Comment: in your question you implemented the wrong library implementation('io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.2') , you need to add implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2") with -compose

Comment: Please refer to https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/